# How to merge two instances of the same type for updating a record in Azure Table Storage

Tags: c#-4.0, azure-table-storage

This is my class that represents a type of some records I've saved into Azure Table Storage.

```
public class UserType : TableEntity
{
    public enum eGenderType { None, Male, Female }
    public virtual DateTime BornDate { get; set; }
    public Guid ConfirmationCode { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual bool? Enabled { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual eGenderType Gender { get; set; }
    public virtual string Surname { get; set; }

    public UserType Get()
    {
        TableQuery<UserType> Query = new TableQuery<UserType>().Where("PartitionKey eq '" + Email + "' and RowKey eq '" + ConfirmationCode + "'");
        UserType User = GetFromTable(Query).FirstOrDefault();

        Type InstanceType = GetType();
        foreach (PropertyInfo Property in typeof(UserType).GetProperties(BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            PropertyInfo InstanceProperty = InstanceType.GetProperty(Property.Name, BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
            if (Property.PropertyType.IsValueType && Equals(InstanceProperty.GetValue(this), Activator.CreateInstance(Property.PropertyType)))
                InstanceProperty.SetValue(this, Property.GetValue(User));
            else if (InstanceProperty.GetValue(this) == null)
                InstanceProperty.SetValue(this, Property.GetValue(User));
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        SaveToTable();    // Perform an InsertOrReplace operation on Azure Table Storage
    }
}

public class UserModel : UserType
{
    public void SetFullName()
    {
        Get();
        base.Update();
    }
}
```

Then I've a MVC action that takes the data from a HTTP POST request and bind them in a UserModel object used as data model.

```
[HttpPost]
public void SetFullName(UserModel Model)
{
    Model.SetFullName();
}
```

To update a record in Azure Table Storage I have to update the entire record and I cannot update single fields so I need the old data updated with the new once from model.
In this case in the Model object I've only these properties with value: Email, ConfirmationCode, FirstName and LastName.
The Get() method I call before base.Update has the scope of getting the values from Table and put them into the Model object in the properties that has no value.

In the case where in Table FirstName and LastName are null and in Model they have value, the Update works and record is correctly updated with old and new values. But in the other case, when in Table FirstName and LastName have values and in the model they are null, the Get method put in Model object the old First and Last name so in the Table after the update, instead of null values, I've always the old values.

So, what is the correct way to do this? Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 0):

`else if (InstanceProperty.GetValue(this) == null)
                InstanceProperty.SetValue(this, Property.GetValue(User));`

This code means if the model property's value is null, it will set the user(Get from the talbe) prpoerty's value.
So if the FirstName and LastName is null, it will be replaced by the old model's FirstName and LastName.

If you don't want to set the old model's First and Last name, I suggest you could write an if condition to check the property name.
If the name is "FirstName" or "Surname", you don't call the SetValue method.

More details, you could refer to below codes sample:
Notice: This code is only want to update the firstname or lastname  property.

```
public UserType Get()
    {
        TableQuery<UserType> Query = new TableQuery<UserType>().Where("PartitionKey eq '" + Email + "' and RowKey eq '" + ConfirmationCode + "'");
        UserType User = GetFromTable(Query).FirstOrDefault();

        Type InstanceType = GetType();
        foreach (PropertyInfo Property in typeof(UserType).GetProperties(BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            PropertyInfo InstanceProperty = InstanceType.GetProperty(Property.Name, BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
            if (Property.PropertyType.IsValueType && Equals(InstanceProperty.GetValue(this), Activator.CreateInstance(Property.PropertyType)))
                InstanceProperty.SetValue(this, Property.GetValue(User));
            else if (InstanceProperty.GetValue(this) == null) {
                if (InstanceProperty.Name != "FirstName" && InstanceProperty.Name != "Surname")
                {
                    InstanceProperty.SetValue(this, Property.GetValue(User));
                } 
            }   
        }
        return this;
    }
```

Result:
Get  from the table
[image]
New model:

[image]

After set value:
[image]

Besides, if you want to update the whole entity, you need firstly get the entity to local, then compare the new MVC model with the entity, at last update it.